# Calculating YTM, OAS, etc. in QuantLib with given bond price

Tags: quantlib

I am attempting to use QuantLib to calculate several bond metrics such as yield to maturity, option-adjusted spread, etc.

The catch is that I am already given a market price and thus have no need to create a discounting curve/calculate NPV.

I haven't really found any clear ways of doing this within QL's framework. Is anyone familiar with a solution?

Comment: This answer by Ballabio may be useful https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36028/excel-yield-function-equivalent-in-python-quantlib